# jHipster use enum in specification to find only entites that have one concrete value of Enum

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, jhipster

There is entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString()
@Entity
@Table
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
class DocumentEntity implements Serializable {
    (...)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public DocumentStatus documentStatus;
}
```

I have serializable class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DocumentCriteria implements Serializable, Criteria {
    private StringFilter documentStatus;

(...)
}
```

and auto generated class:

```
@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(DocumentEntity.class)
public abstract class DocumentEntity_ {
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<DocumentEntity, DocumentStatus> documentStatus;
    public static final String DOCUMENT_STATUS = "documentStatus";
    (...)
}
```

`DocumentStatus` is simple `enum`:

```
public enum DocumentStatus {
    A,
    B
}
```

I want to add `specification` that I search only entites with `DocumentStatus` set to `A`:

```
    private Specification<DocumentEntity> createSpecification(DocumentCriteria criteria) {
        Specification<DocumentEntity> specification = Specification.where(null);  
        if (criteria != null) {
            StringFilter globalStringFilter = new StringFilter();
            globalStringFilter.setContains(DocumentStatus.A.name());

            specification.and(buildStringSpecification(globalStringFilter, DocumentEntity_.documentStatus));
```

I have an error here saying:

```
Required type:
SingularAttribute
<? super DocumentEntity,
String>
Provided:
SingularAttribute
<DocumentEntity,
DocumentStatus>
```

How can I search for it?

I tried also:

```
    specification = specification.and(buildSpecification(criteria.getDocumentStatus(), DocumentStatus.A.name());
```

but it says:

```
Cannot resolve method 'buildSpecification(StringFilter, String)
```

Should i use other type than `StringFilter` even though database type is `varchar` ?

Does trying using String like: `DocumentStatus.A.name()` does not help here ?

Another option that comes in my head is writing something like that:

```
    RangeFilter<DocumentStatus> globalStringFilter = new RangeFilter<DocumentStatus>();
        List<DocumentStatus> documentStatuses = new ArrayList<>();
        documentStatuses.add(DocumentStatus.A);
        globalStringFilter.setIn(documentStatuses);
    specification.and(buildRangeSpecification(globalStringFilter, DocumentEntity_.documentStatus));
```

And changing `DocumentCriteria` `documentStatus` field type to `RangeFilter`.

Above option does not seem to take effect when running application.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
 RangeFilter<DocumentStatus> globalStringFilter = new RangeFilter<DocumentStatus>();
        List<DocumentStatus> documentStatuses = new ArrayList<>();
        documentStatuses.add(DocumentStatus.A);
        globalStringFilter.setIn(documentStatuses);
        specification=specification.and(buildRangeSpecification(globalStringFilter, DocumentEntity_.documentStatus));
```

And changing `DocumentCriteria` `documentStatus` field type to `RangeFilter`.

Make sure that `specification=` is present, so that result is consumed.